# Why there are different ways to set label text on Qt Installer Framework?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-installer

With [Qt Installer Controller Script](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html#introduction-page) I see how to change the text of some labels on the Introduction page. I did

```
function Controller()
{
}

Controller.prototype.IntroductionPageCallback = function()
{

    var widget = gui.currentPageWidget();
    if (widget != null) {
        widget.title = "New title"; 
        widget.MessageLabel.setText("New Message."); 
    }
}
```

Why they work differently?
To set `title` I do `= "New title"` but to set `MessageLabel` I do `.setText("New Message.")`.

Comment: Because that's how the developer decided to implement these. One as a property, the other one as a method.

Comment: How can one find out which way should be used? Try both and see which one works?

Comment: @KcFnMi Both ways are valid, in C++ it would be like: `wizardPage->setTitle("Foo")` and `wizardPage->setProperty("title", "Foo")`. That is, the C++ qproperties are exposed as properties.

Comment: I tried `widget.title.setText("New title")` and unless I did something else wrong it didn't worked. Also tried `widget.MessageLabel = "New Message"` and it also don't seem to work. Why do you say "both ways are valid"?